# ROC curve only has few points

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, roc, auc

I have a training set that has 141 objects and a testing set that has 15 objects. I trained a SVM classifier and would like to plot the ROC curve to visualize the performance. The codes I used are:

```
training_fold = feature.selected.matrix[-x,] # training fold =  training set minus (-) it's sub test fold
test_fold = feature.selected.matrix[x,] # here we describe the test fold individually

classifier = svm(formula = Outcome ~ .,
               data = training_fold,
               type = 'C-classification',
               kernel = 'radial',
               gamma = 0.01,
               cost = 3, decision.value = TRUE)      
y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = test_fold[,-ncol(test_fold)],  decision.value = TRUE)


fitted = attributes(y_pred)$decision.values  

predob = prediction(fitted, test_fold$Outcome)


perf = performance(pred , 'fpr', 'tpr')
perf
plot(perf)   #dev.off()
```

This gives a plot that contains only 16 points, which makes the curve not smooth.
[image]
Also, the AUC is extremely small (~0.18), even though the accuracy is over 80%. Can anyone help me explain this?

Comment: Sorry for the missing, I corrected in the question

Comment: With 15 data points you can have only 16 points on the ROC curve. You need more data.